# Probability: Customer boarding taxi (Queue Problem).

Tags: probability, probability-theory, poisson-process, exponential-distribution

> > Three passengers with different destinations board a shared taxi. The
> >     times between successive stops are independent exponential random
> >     variables of rate $\lambda$. At each stop one passenger leaves the
> >     taxi. This takes no time, and no additional passenger enter. A
> >     departing passenger walks home, and indepdently of everything else,
> >     the time this takes is an exponential random variable of rate $\mu$.
>
> a) Suppose that the last passenger leaves the taxi at time $t$. If one
>   of the first two passengers left the taxi at time $s$ (which of course
>   is less than $t$), what is the probability that passenger is already
>   home by time $t$?
>
> b) Suppose that the last passenger leaves the taxi at time $t$. What
>   is the probability  that both of the other passengers are already home
>   by time $t$?

---

---

**Attempt**:

**a)** This is a poisson process $N(t)$. A passenger leaves at time $s$,  and the walk time is ~$Exp$.

$\Rightarrow P(time\leq t-s)=1-e^{-\mu(t-s)}$ .

(Concern: does "one of the two customer leaves at time $s$" factor into my calculation? If so, how should I reflect that?)

**b)** Condition on $N(t)=3$, the two passengers leave the taxi with probability $3!/t^3$.

For this part, I am really confuse mainly because I am not clear about the concept of conditional arrival times in poisson process.

Comment: The attempt has been updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer for a) is correct. For b), conditioning on the last passenger leaving at $t$ leaves the other two passengers' departure times uniformly distributed over $[0,t]$ (since no matter when they depart, the times in the exponents in the product of the probabilities will add up to the constant sum $t$). Thus the probability that a given one of them is home is

$$
\frac1t\int_0^t\left(1-\mathrm e^{-\mu(t-s)}\right)\mathrm ds=1-\frac1{\mu t}\left(1-\mathrm e^{-\mu t}\right)\;,
$$

and the probability that they are both home is the square of that.

Comment: Another question asked is :"What is the distribution of the time the last passenger leaves the taxi? Give its name and any parameter(s)".

Comment: I guess the answer should be Gamma (3,$\lambda$), since we are summing 3 independent exponential variables.

Comment: @randy: That looks right.